# TInyMce removing Bold tags when number list when saving form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, tinymce

I have used tinymce editor for one of my textarea, I have formatting option where user can format the text like bold, underlin, italic and etc the code is as follows:

```
tinymce.init({
    branding: false,
    statusbar: false,
    resize:true,
    height : height,
    selector: '#' + elemId,
    plugins : 'code | advlist autolink lists charmap preview lists',
    toolbar: "code | undo redo | italic | underline | bold | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | removeformat",
    menubar: 'file edit insert view tools help',
    formats:{
        underline : {inline : 'u', exact : true}
    },
    paste_block_drop: false,
    paste_as_text: false,
    paste_data_images: false,
    paste_postprocess: (editor, args) => {
        console.log(editor);
        args.content += ' preprocess';
    },
    removed_menuitems: 'newdocument print',
    contextmenu: false,
    inline_styles: false,
    valid_children : 'span[style]',
    invalid_elements : 'style, form, input, button, textarea, select, i, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, img, table, td, tr, th, a',
    onchange_callback: 'editorOnChange',
    on_paste_remove_styles:true,
    forced_root_block: false,
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('keyup', function (e) {
            let tinyElem = $('.tox-tinymce');
            let textElem = $('.tinymce');
            if(editor.getContent().length > 0){
                let style = tinyElem.attr('style').replace('#dc3545', '#6c757d');
                tinyElem.attr('style', style);
                textElem.removeClass('is-invalid');
                textElem.siblings('.form-label').removeClass('error');
            }else if(editor.getContent().length == 0){
                let style = tinyElem.attr('style').replace('#6c757d', '#dc3545');
                tinyElem.attr('style', style);
                textElem.addClass('is-invalid');
                textElem.siblings('.form-label').addClass('error');
            }
        });
        editor.on('PastePreProcess', function(e){
            // Prevent TinyMCE from pasting emojis
            e.content = e.content.replace(/([\u2700-\u27BF]|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\uD83C[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\u2011-\u26FF]|\uD83E[\uDD10-\uDDFF])/g, '');
        });

    }
});
```

now when i submit the form input it remove the strong tag from the bold text and return simple p tag

[image: My Source code of entered input]

Actual Output is as follows:

[image: Actual Out put]

Can someone check if there is anything wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind, Just recalled that I have used tag filter middle ware to allow certain tags and remove some of the them like this, added strong and ol tashsin the list now working

```
array_walk_recursive($input, function (&$input) {
        $allowedTags = ['p', 'b', 'u', 'i', 'ul', 'li'];
        $input = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode($input), $allowedTags);
    });
```